# How do I add a provider for the package type in Puppet?

Tags: puppet, ruby

The [puppet-rvm](https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm) FAQ mentions that they didn't extend the `package` type because "it becomes harder to manage multiple Ruby versions and nearly impossible to install gems for a specific Ruby version". I don't need multiple Ruby versions, nor gems for them.

The author of puppet-rvm is implying that it's possible to extend puppet types. Google searching on the topic failed to turn up anything of interest. How does one extend built-in puppet types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you searched, but all information can be found on puppet [docs site](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/).

You can add stuff in all sort of ways to Puppet. There are four main categories which are:

- [Custom facts](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html)
- [Custom functions](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html)
- [Custom resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_types.html)
- [Custom providers](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/provider_development.html) (also same link as resources)

There's even a [complete example](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/complete_resource_example.html) of new resources.

Comment: Thank you. According to my browser history logs I google searched for the phrase "puppet add provider" and mild variations thereon. Interestingly enough, now that I've clicked on the links you've provided these are the top results for the phrase above.

Comment: Also, a working custom package provider is at https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey